# Macro bugs on sheet change

Tags: vba, excel

I have been working on a project with Excel. Thanks to Stack Overflow users :), I have couple of worksheet_change macros. Everything works flawlessly but one of them gives run-time error '1004' in some cases.

```
  Application.ScreenUpdating = False
If Target.Count > 1 Then Exit Sub
If Target.Column <= 25 Then
    If Target.value <> "" Then
    Range("A" & Target.Row & ":Y" & Target.Row).Select
    Selection.borders(xlDiagonalDown).LineStyle = xlNone
    Selection.borders(xlDiagonalUp).LineStyle = xlNone

        With Selection.borders
        .LineStyle = xlContinuous
        .Weight = xlThin
        .ColorIndex = xlAutomatic
    End With

    Selection.borders(xlInsideHorizontal).LineStyle = xlContinuous
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    End If
End If
```

So everytime I enter data in a cell, macro puts borders automatically starting from Column A till Column Y. It works alright but if a cell is selected (not a single selection but double click selection into the cell), if I try to change the sheet it gives me an error with this highlighted line:

```
Range("A" & Target.Row & ":Y" & Target.Row).Select
```

I could just deselect the cell and change sheets but I was wondering if it could be fixed within the macro?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no need to select at all:

```
If Target.Column <= 25 Then
    If Target.Value <> "" Then
        With Range("A" & Target.Row & ":Y" & Target.Row)
            .Borders(xlDiagonalDown).LineStyle = xlNone
            .Borders(xlDiagonalUp).LineStyle = xlNone

            With .Borders
                .LineStyle = xlContinuous
                .Weight = xlThin
                .ColorIndex = xlAutomatic
            End With

            .Borders(xlInsideHorizontal).LineStyle = xlContinuous
        End With
        Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    End If
End If
```

Comment: Damn, as easy as that. thank you so much Rory! It's better now :)